# Open Graph object type for secondary pages in local business website

Tags: seo, meta-tags, local-seo, social-media, open-graph-protocol

I'm developping a website for a local business, and I don't know what is the most pertinent `og:type` to chose for pages like "about us", "other services", "contact us" and so on...

As stated in the [OG doc site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/website/) for the `website` type:

> This object type represents a website. It is a simple object type and
>   uses only common Open Graph properties. **For specific pages within a
>   website, the `article` object type should be used**.

Should the above rule be applied also for other object types? like the `business.business` type? 
Should I always apply the [business type](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/business.business/) for all the pages or only for the home page and switch to `article` for the the other "secondary pages"?

PS.

My term "secondary page" maybe is a little misguiding, since those are not "secondary" as importance but only in *"logic structure"*, so to speak. Giving the "primary page" role to the "home" page is indeed right in a logic view, but as importance for the business maybe other pages like "services", "products", "contacts" and so on, are even more important instead of the home page that should act mostly as presentation and direct viewers to the other pages of the site.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there are varying standards for this, and there isn't really a 'subpage' tag. I normally default to `article` because it seems the most appropriate. Facebook also agrees with this, as you mentioned.

> For specific pages within a website, the article object type should be used.

I've never had any issues with this regarding indexing or SEO and in my opinion it is the most appropriate.

As far as `business.business` goes, I believe this is somewhat Facebook specific but I would include it on every page if you are going to use it at all.

Comment: I've updated my question to clear a point that you raised.
Unfortunately I see also that only 1 object type is accepted per page, so I guess I should go for the business.business as you suggest.
I'll keep the question open a bit more to see if there is some more discussion on this.